# How to capture value of listbox item

Tags: c#, windows-phone, listpicker

I am trying to capture the value of the selected item in a list box, and store that value into my database. My goal is when I choose "Male" (or "Female") the "Male" (or "Female") will be added to the Gender [column] in the database but I don't know how to do it.

MyDatabase:

```
[Table]
    public class Member : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        // Define ID: private field, public property, and database column.
        private int _ID;

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            set
            {
                if (_ID != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("ID");
                    _ID = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _FullName;

        [Column]
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return _FullName; }
            set
            {
                if (_FullName != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("FullName");
                    _FullName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("FullName");
                }
            }
        }



        private string _Address;
        [Column]
        public string Address
        {
            get { return _Address; }
            set
            {
                if (_Address != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Address");
                    _Address = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Address");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _Gender;

        [Column]
        public string Gender
        {
            get { return _Gender; }
            set
            {
                if (_Gender != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Gender");
                    _FullName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Gender");
                }
            }
        }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Used to notify that a property changed
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
        #region INotifyPropertyChanging Members

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        // Used to notify that a property is about to change
        private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanging != null)
            {
                PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
    public class GenderPicker
    {
        public string sex
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

My ListPicker list:

```
public Add()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = App.MainViewModel;
        List<GenderPicker> picker = new List<GenderPicker>();
        picker.Add(new GenderPicker() { sex = "Male" });
        picker.Add(new GenderPicker() { sex = "FeMale" });
        this.ListPicker.ItemsSource = picker;


    }
```

My Add Button: I dont know what can be filled in ???????????????

Member is the table. Column is FullName | Address | Gender

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((addaddress.Text.Length > 0) && (addfullname.Text.Length > 0))
        {
            Member newInfo = new Member
            {
                FullName = addfullname.Text,
                Address = addaddress.Text,
                Gender = ????????????????

            };
            App.MainViewModel.Addinfo(newInfo);
        }
    }
```

And my selection changed in LIstpicker:

```
  private void ListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var samplesex =(GenderPicker)ListPicker.SelectedItem;
        var selectedsex = (samplesex.sex).ToString();

    }
```

Comment: What kind of database are you trying to connect to?  Have you researched connecting the specific database with .net?  More information available MSDN most likely in System.Data namespace

Comment: I have added my database in to question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?  [Found on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17400123/1580661)

```
(ListPicker.SelectedItem as GenderPicker).sex.ToString()
```

or in your example:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((addaddress.Text.Length > 0) && (addfullname.Text.Length > 0))
    {
        Member newInfo = new Member
        {
            FullName = addfullname.Text,
            Address = addaddress.Text,
            Gender = (ListPicker.SelectedItem as GenderPicker).sex.ToString()

        };
        App.MainViewModel.Addinfo(newInfo);
    }
}
```

you could/should make a property to have a default value so you don't receive NullReference exceptions if ListPicker has a NULL selected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired `gender = picker.SelectedValue.ToString();`

[Here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-listbox-selecteditem) is more information on using the `ListBox` control on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is about the data structure.

Why are you using a 'GenderPicker' class to choose genders?  Do GenderPicker classes have function?

Why not use an Enumerator?

```
public enum Gender: int
{
    Male=0,
    Female=1,
    Pat=-1
}
```

This would allow you to just store a int column in your database.  Also this is easy to convert back into a Gender.

```
int GenderInt = Gender.Pat; // -1
Gender whatIsPat = (Gender)GenderInt; // Gender.Pat
```